# ORA-04063 "SYS_ALL_QUEUE_TABLES" has errors

Tags: sql, oracle

I've created a database and i found some tables on it so i dropped them all after dropping them i found this error message every time i try to open tables or views in any database

[image]

so i removed all the tables expecting that this may but it didn't

Comment: Which *some tables* did you drop? And for what reason?

Comment: And from which schema(s)? If you dropped tables from SYS (which the error suggests) or other built-in schemas then you've destroyed your database. You could restore from a backup if you have one, otherwise you pretty much need to throw it away and start again. Normally catastrophic, but if you've just created it maybe just a valuable learning experience this time. ["the SYS schema ... should never be modified ..."](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/admin/getting-started-with-database-administration.html#GUID-4D97A18C-0690-4293-9093-FB7732D0E8AC)

Comment: Yeah, I guess I did that then I deleted all the connections I have. but now every time I create a new connection I get the same error what should I do now? I guess I don't have a backup also